# Editable (jQuery In Place Editor): How to make text that was not selected, editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing some experimenting (so the code below has lots of stuff that I wouldn't normally put in).  I have pairs of spans (that have the same ID).  In this exampel there are 2 with ID=42 and 2 with ID=43.  Currently, when I click on the text of one of the ID=42s, both ID 42s highlight in red.

Using the plugin from http://arashkarimzadeh.com/index.php/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html, I added

```
$(function(){$('.test').editable()});
```

And that allows the text that is selected to become editable.  What I want to do, is if ID=42 is clicked, the other ID=42 is editable -- not the one that is clicked.  There will only ever be a max of two IDs with the same ID.  What can I add to this code to loop through and make the change?

```
.selected { color:red; }

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.editable-1.3.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){$('.test').editable()});

$(".testClass").click(function () {
    if ( $('.testClass').hasClass('selected') ) {
        $('.testClass').removeClass('selected');                    
    }           
    var thisTarget = $(this).attr('id');            
    $('#container').find('#'+thisTarget).toggleClass("selected", 1000);             
    return false;
});

</script>




<p>
<span id="42" class="testClass">            
    <span class="test">Click me (I need to turn red)</span>     
</span>
</p>
<p>
<span id="43" class="testClass">            
    <span class="test">just another test</span>
</span>     
</p>        
<p>
<span id="42" class="testClass">            
    <span class="test">And I become editable</span>
</span>     
</p>        
<p>
<span id="43" class="testClass">            
    <span class="test">just another test</span>
</span>     
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there's no such thing as two of the same ID. IDs are *always* unique, meaning that you cannot have more than one on the same page that has the same name. (I'm also a little confused because although you say there are two 42s and two 43s, there is actually only one of each in your code. Make sure you understand that the child `<span>` does *not* have an ID of 42 or 43.) PS: IDs/classes cannot begin with numerals.

If you want to click on `.test` and then manipulate its parent (`id=42`), that's fairly simple to do:

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    // Manipulate the parent (id=42, 43) however you want here
    parent.css('background', '#000');
});
```

I'm unfamiliar with the plugin you linked, but using this method you should be able to manipulate the parent however you want. However, I don't really see how this should be a problem for you, since you can just as easily attach the `onclick` event to `id=42`, or for your purposes, use the following:

`$(function(){$('#42, #43').editable()});`

Comment: Re: starting with numerals, thanks for the reminder.  there are 2 42s and 43s... there's 4 paragraphs up there...  The sections or spans in question are not parent child... I guess they would be called "siblings".

Comment: Oh, on 2nd look, the reason why the spans are numeric is because I stripped out my prefix before posting :)

Comment: Wow, I must have just not noticed there was more content. (I forgot to scroll.) Nevertheless, you cannot have two IDs with the same name. Your CSS and JS will become unpredictable at best. Does my answer satisfy your question?

Comment: Can two elements share the same ID if they are referenced in an iFrame?